# Drawable is not displayed each time when opening a new activity

Tags: java, android

I have this really basic application where im trying to display an image of a dice randomly. At this stage I am trying to figure out why the dice is not displayed at all times in the new activity. The problem occurs when I start the second activity from the spinner, and sometimes I can start the second activity multiple times and its working fine, and then suddenly the dice is dissappeard. This only happens when I try to roll the dice from the spinner in main activity, and not when pressing the button in second activity.

I hope someone could help me out here!

Main Activity

```
  package com.example.t.diceapplication;

  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
  import android.widget.AdapterView;
  import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
  import android.widget.Spinner;
  import android.widget.Toast;

  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

Spinner spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.NmbrOfDiceArray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    if (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 1) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, OneDiceActivity.class));
    }

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    spinner.setSelection(0);
}
}
```

Second Activity

```
  package com.example.t.diceapplication;

  import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.ImageView;

  import java.util.Random;

  public class OneDiceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView imageView;
Button button;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_one_dice);

    imageView=findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    button=findViewById(R.id.button);

    DisplayDice();
}

public void DisplayDice(){

    if (getRandomNumber()==1){
        imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable._diceone));
    }

    else if(getRandomNumber()==2){
        imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable._dicetwo));
    }

    else if (getRandomNumber()==3){
        imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable._dicethree));
    }

    else if (getRandomNumber()==4){
        imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable._dicefour));
    }

    else if (getRandomNumber()==5){
        imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable._dicefive));
    }

    else if (getRandomNumber()==6){
        imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable._dicesix));
    }
}

public void rollDiceOnButtonClick(View view){
    DisplayDice();
}

public int getRandomNumber(){
    Random r = new Random();
    int Low = 1;
    int High = 6;
    return r.nextInt((High-Low)+1) + Low;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    this.finish();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an issue with your `if` logic. You're getting a random number in every condition which could lead to none of your `if` branches being true. Try this instead. You only need to get the random number once.

```
    public void DisplayDice(){

        int diceRandom = getRandomNumber();

        // replace other instances to this method call with the variable
        if (diceRandom ==1){
 imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable._diceone));
        }
    ....
    }
```